# Is there a horizontal line class in Java, similar to the Point / Rectangle classes?

Tags: java, awt, line

I'm looking for a simple line class, similar to `java.awt.Point`. But rather than storing the x,y coordinates, it only stores x1 and x2, referring to the start and end x coordinates of the line?

I simply want to store data on a horizontal line, i.e its width, and its start / end locations on the x axis. A look through `java.awt` and `java.awt.geom` hasn't given any results.

Comment: You can try extending http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean, something like [`Line2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html)

Check out [Drawing Geometric Primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html) for more details...

If you "really" need just a horizontal line, you could make your own using `Line2D`, for example...

```
public class HorizontalLine extends Line2D.Double {

    public HorizontalLine(double x1, double x2) {
        super(x1, 0, x2, 0);
    }

}
```

This has the added benefit of working with the rest of the `Shape` API...

nb- You will become responsible for translating it's `y` position though...

Comment: That one's pretty good, but it also needs y1 and y2 to be specified. I'm looking for something explicitly horizontal, which only needs x1 and x2.

Comment: Then I would say - no.

Comment: @user2790209:- Are you looking for this:- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html ???

Comment: @RahulTripathi No, just a simple class that lets you specify its x1 and x2. Guess I'll have to write my own.

Comment: @user2790209:- Yes for sure!!! As I dont think that there is any class like that!!

Comment: Why did they provide only `Double` and `Float` implementations for `Line2D`? Why no integer / long implementions

Comment: @user2790209 only Double and Float, because most of methods implemented in API (Essential classes too) are based, has implemented double ..., reasons how those methods are created, implemented in  history

Comment: The `geom` API was designed to provide functionality for high precision graphics output, such as printing, which can have fractions of precision, unlike screens...

Comment: If it's really niggly, just change the parameters for class to what you "feel" you need and convert them as required internally...

Comment: If I use Line2DFloat and supply integers as the values, will it accurately store / return them?

Comment: The question is, what do you want to do with the class?  If you want to use it as part of the `Graphics2D` API, the using something like `Line2D` is a reasonable solution.  If you just want to use it as a container, you would probably be better off creating your own "line" implementation...IMHO

Answer (score 3):

There is no "horizontal like segment" class in the standard API. It is trivial to create one, though:

```
public class HorizontalLine {
    private double start;
    private double end;
    // add methods and attributes you need
}
```